# CustomView: добавление атрибутов по умолчанию

Tags: android, xml, customview

Создаю кастомную View, наследника FrameLayout.
Я задал ей несколько атрибутов, которые хочу редактировать в XML.
Все работает хорошо и правильно.
НО!

Я не пишу код в самой разметке XML, а люблю перетаскивать элемент из Design. Вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и конечно же, этих параметров там нет по умолчанию:

```
<com.example.customview.ElementView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Если же так сделать с Button, то там будет сразу параметр "имени кнопки":

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Как мне сделать так же, чтобы у меня были сразу такие предустановленные атрибуты, когда я перетаскиваю элемент в разметку?

Comment: Вряд ли такое возможно, слишком специфическое и редкое требование, из-за чего оно вряд ли реализовано доступным простым смертным.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб жалко. очень хотелось бы просто вытащить элемент - а там уже предустановлены какие-то параметры и сразу видишь, на что они влияют.